# Nuts and raisins don't stick to cookies after baking

Tags: cookies

I decorated my cookies with raisins and nuts, but no matter how deep I pressed them into the dough, they fell off after baking. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely happens when the fat in the cookie dough sizzles out and make the nuts & raisins slip out, or the cookies expand greatly during baking, pushing out the nuts & raisins.

If possible, try reducing the fat content and the amount of leavening agent of the cookies. Another solution is to roll out a paper thin layer of dough to press onto the tops of the cookies.

If the problem really is due to excessive expanding of the cookies, flipping them upside-down on the baking sheet before placing them in the over might help.